# Log all Google Chrome browser activity

Tags: beginner, bash, shell, google-chrome, applescript

This script documents every website visited and writes the text content of each webpage to its own individual file. It seems to work as intended. Is there anything I could do to improve it?

```
#!/bin/bash

#####################
##### Functions #####
#####################

chrome() {

    osascript -e \
    'tell application "Google_Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1 to execute javascript "document.body.innerText"' 2>&1

}

set_variables() {

    ds="$(date +%Y_%m_%d)"
    url="$(osascript -e 'tell app "Google_Chrome" to tell the active tab of window 1 to get the url as text' 2>&1 | grep -v '78:82: execution error')"
    title="$(osascript -e 'tell application "Google_Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1 to get the title as text' 2>&1 | grep -v '84:88: execution error')" 
    site="$(echo "$url" | awk -F '/' '{OFS="/"} { print $3 }')"
    page="$(echo "${site%.*}" | sed 's/www.//g')"
    name="$(echo "$url" | awk -F '/' '{OFS="/"} { print $4 }')"
    if [[ "$name" = '' ]]; then 
        name="$page"
    fi
    dir="$HOME/Logfiles/$page/$ds"
    if [ ! -d "${dir}" ]; then 
        mkdir -p "${dir}"
    fi
    doc="$name.txt"
    tmp="${doc}_temporary.txt"
    file="${dir}/${doc}"
    if [[ $url = '' ]]; then 
        echo -e "\nAll browser windows have closed\nNow exiting\n" && exit
    fi
    echo

}

##################
##### Script #####
##################

while true
do
    set_variables
    echo -e "$ds\n----------\n$site\n$title\n" | tee -a "$file"
    while true
    do 
        current_url="$(osascript -e 'tell app "Google_Chrome" to tell the active tab of window 1 to get the url as text' 2>&1 | grep -v '78:82: execution error')"

        if [[ "$current_url" != "$url" ]]; then
            awk '!seen[$0]++' "$file" >> "$tmp"
            cat "$tmp" > "$file"
            rm "$tmp"
            break 1
        # example regex for specific websites
        elif [[ "$current_url" = https://example.com/*/ ]]; then
            regex='[[:alnum:]]'
        else
            regex='[\p{L}]'
        fi

        chrome | while read -r lines
        do 
            echo "$lines" | grep -E $regex
        done
    done | awk '!seen[$0]++ { print; fflush() }' | tee -a "$file"
done
```